# pcap and raw socket

Tags: linux, networking, c, socket

I want to develop an application (module or user-level if possible) to create a raw socket in RHEL stealing all level-2 packets directly from kernel (without being routed or handled by other open sockets). I would like to feed packets to pcap to programatically handle some packet types. What would be the best of doing it? I have seen articles on zero copy networking, pcap, BPF but I guess they are all working with packet captures/copies?

Comment: @Mat, for my education what exactly is off topic about that question? I'd agree it's poorly asked, but I can't see why it would be off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give the interface an IP address. Just bring it up, and capture packets with libpcap. If it's got no IP address, the kernel will leave it alone if that's your concern.

If you want the interface to have an IP address handled by the kernel and redirect only some IP packets to your application, netfilter can do it. Look at the NFQUEUE or NFLOG iptables target.

If packet capture performance is your concern, look at [PF_RING](http://www.ntop.org/products/pf_ring/).

Otherwise, maybe you can explain in more detail what you're trying to do as it's unclear to me.